# Error on room database migration test, due to a wrong "primaryKeyPosition" value

Tags: database-migration, android-room

I am testing a room migration and on the "migration and validation" step I got an **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration failed.** due to a wrong `primaryKeyPosition` value on the "service_id" column. Digging a little bit deeper I noticed that on the **Expected** side the attributes in the *actual_visit_id_service_id_primary_key* have different *pk* indexes (1, 2), while on the **Found** side, both have the same (1, 1)

I checked into the database schema of table *actual_visit_service* in the installed app and the *pk* for the column *service_id* is 2 (like expected)

The failing entity:

```java
@Entity(
    tableName = ACTUAL_VISIT_SERVICE_TABLE,
    indices = [Index(
        value = [ACTUAL_VISIT_SERVICE_SERVICE_ID, ACTUAL_VISIT_SERVICE_ACTUAL_VISIT_ID], unique = true
    )],
    foreignKeys = [(ForeignKey(
        entity = ActualVisitEntity::class,
        parentColumns = [ID],
        childColumns = [ACTUAL_VISIT_SERVICE_ACTUAL_VISIT_ID],
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    ))],
    primaryKeys = [ACTUAL_VISIT_SERVICE_ACTUAL_VISIT_ID, ACTUAL_VISIT_SERVICE_SERVICE_ID]
)
data class ActualVisitServicesEntity(
    @ColumnInfo(name = ACTUAL_VISIT_SERVICE_ACTUAL_VISIT_ID)
    val actualVisitId: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = ACTUAL_VISIT_SERVICE_AMOUNT)
    val amount: Double?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = ACTUAL_VISIT_SERVICE_DURATION)
    val duration: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = IS_SYNCHRONIZED)
    var isSynchronized: Boolean = false,
    @ColumnInfo(name = ACTUAL_VISIT_SERVICE_HAS_BEEN_PROVIDED)
    var hasBeenProvided: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(name = ACTUAL_VISIT_SERVICE_REJECTION_CATEGORY)
    var rejectionCategory: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = ACTUAL_VISIT_SERVICE_REJECTION_REASON)
    var rejectionReason: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = ACTUAL_VISIT_SERVICE_SERVICE_ID)
    val serviceId: String
) : BaseEntity() {
....
}
```

The migration:

```java
        @JvmField
        val MIGRATION_18_TO_19 = object : Migration(18, 19) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE planned_visit ADD COLUMN hint TEXT")
            }
        }
```

The error I got:

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration failed.
Expected:TableInfo{name='actual_visit_services', columns={duration=Column{name='duration', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, amount=Column{name='amount', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, actual_visit_id=Column{name='actual_visit_id', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, rejection_category=Column{name='rejection_category', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, has_been_provided=Column{name='has_been_provided', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, service_id=Column{name='service_id', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=2}, rejection_reason=Column{name='rejection_reason', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, is_synchronized=Column{name='is_synchronized', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='actual_visits', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[actual_visit_id], referenceColumnNames=[id]}], indices=[Index{name='index_actual_visit_services_service_id_actual_visit_id', unique=true, columns=[service_id, actual_visit_id]}]} 
found:TableInfo{name='actual_visit_services', columns={duration=Column{name='duration', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, amount=Column{name='amount', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, actual_visit_id=Column{name='actual_visit_id', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, rejection_category=Column{name='rejection_category', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, has_been_provided=Column{name='has_been_provided', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, service_id=Column{name='service_id', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, rejection_reason=Column{name='rejection_reason', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, is_synchronized=Column{name='is_synchronized', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='actual_visits', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[actual_visit_id], referenceColumnNames=[id]}], indices=null}
```

As you see on "Expected" you have:

```
service_id=Column{name= ... primaryKeyPosition=2}
```

but on "Found":

```
service_id=Column{name= ... primaryKeyPosition=1}
```

I use Room from the beginning but I just started with the migrations, being the previous database build version 18 and the new one 19. I run the regular entities and DAOs test with `Robolectric` and I intend to do the same with the migration tests.

Why do the two attributes in the composed primary key have the same *pk* index in the migrated database?

Comment: This is a known issue with Robolectric due to unmatching sqlite versions
Issues on Google and Robolectric:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142404973

https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/4209

Possible solution could be using https://github.com/guness/RobolectricSQLite for now