# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle. Tables not changed

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, testing, room

I have a problem when trying to write example test for room migration. When I run test i got above exception, however the table that causes the problem did not change between db versions.

```html
Expected: TableInfo{name='UserSettings', columns={userLocalId=Column{name='userLocalId', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, value=Column{name='value', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, key=Column{name='key', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=2, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]} 
found: TableInfo{name='UserSettings', columns={userLocalId=Column{name='userLocalId', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, value=Column{name='value', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, key=Column{name='key', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=null}
```

I can see the difference between found and expecteded but I dont know what caused it.
My UserSettings.kt class:

```html
@Entity(tableName = "UserSettings", primaryKeys = ["userLocalId", "key"])
data class UserSettingsEntity(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "userLocalId") val userLocalId: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "key") val key: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "value") val value: String
)
```

**Edit**
Found out its known issue for Roboelectric and migration tests.
[Error on room database migration test, due to a wrong "primaryKeyPosition" value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57875012/error-on-room-database-migration-test-due-to-a-wrong-primarykeyposition-value)

Answer (score 0):

it's typo error , please check word type for column name value

value=Column{name='value', **tye**='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true

Comment: I made this errror when pasting, these files are generated when running test. Thanks for noticing tho